# Angular pre-built theme is not working for Angular8 library

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-library

Pre-built Angular Material Theme is not working in a library in the same way like in an angular app. Created a style.css file in projects/example-lib folder and imported pre-built indigo-pink theme within it. As per the documentation, I should be including it in angular.json file, but on doing that, I get the following error

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(styles).
```

Angular Material design components (Mat-Tabs, etc..) work in my library, but **angular material theme** is not working. I have also tried adding to my styles.css the following,

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

which also didn't work. I think the pre-built theme is not getting applied because the style.css file is not globally defined. Also added ViewEncapsulation.None to the root component of the library to remove encapsulation. It doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

this is from angular material website, it may be helpful:

> Finally, if your app's content is not placed inside of a mat-sidenav-container element, you need to add the mat-app-background class to your wrapper element (for example the body). This ensures that the proper theme background is applied to your page.

Comment: I did add mat-app-background class to my wrapper element and it didn't apply the pre-built theme.

Comment: Also, I get a warning in the developer's console saying that "Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected."

Comment: I hope u find an answer but we realy don't have a lot to work with, give us more details, add some could and errors stack.

Answer (score 0):

Angular pre-built theme was not working for a library because it wasn't defined globally. It basically means that my stylesheet was not entered in the styles[] in angular.json file.
The following solution works well for defining styles globally
https://medium.com/@Dor3nz/compiling-css-in-new-angular-6-libraries-26f80274d8e5

1. Install ng-packagr, scss-bundle, and ts-node
2. Create a css-bundle.ts https://gist.github.com/Dor3nz/2a33196d2f4b0db7d5ac5904941f5a1b#file-css-bundle-ts
3. Add _theme.scss inside the /src directory of the library that actually contains and imports all the css that we want to bundle.
4. Add postbuild npm script to run the css-bundle.ts
5. Include it in the styles tag in your Application in the angular.json